# How do I get one result for more products and translate it to PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT `address_1`, `city` FROM `wntl_virtuemart_order_userinfos` 
WHERE exists
(SELECT `order_item_sku` FROM `wntl_virtuemart_order_items`
WHERE order_item_sku = 5.
and product_quantity   >= 1)`
```

How do I get one result per address?
Currently, if someone ordered 3 products the query returns this address 3 times. I just need this 1 time.

And another question is how do I translate this to a PHP file?

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

use the GROUP BY Statement. In your example, it would be **GROUP BY address_1**

```
SELECT `address_1`, `city` FROM `wntl_virtuemart_order_userinfos` WHERE exists (SELECT order_item_sku from wntl_virtuemart_order_items where order_item_sku = 5 and product_quantity >= 1) GROUP BY address_1
```

PHP Implementation:

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT `address_1`, `city` FROM `wntl_virtuemart_order_userinfos` WHERE exists (SELECT order_item_sku from wntl_virtuemart_order_items where order_item_sku = 5 and product_quantity >= 1) GROUP BY address_1';

try {
   $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
   foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {
      print_r($row);
   }
   $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
   die();
}
?>
```